# How to run GPS Location listener in background using service - Android

Tags: android

I need to track the user's location using background,and then need to send to the server via socket. 
Using an activity i have done and it's working fine, but when i go with service i couldn't. Can any one please help me?

public class GpsService extends Service implements LocationListener{

```
      static final String TAG ="MobileTracking";

     public Context mycontext;

  public boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

   public Location location; // location
    public double latitude; // latitude
   public double longitude; // longitude
   public String datetext;//date and time  

   TelephonyManager telephoneManager;

     // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // 1 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute


    public  Location getLocation()
    {
         try
            {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) mycontext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                // getting GPS status
                isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                // getting network status
                isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
                {
                    // no network provider is enabled
                }
                else
                {
                    this.canGetLocation = true;

                    // First get location from Network Provider
                    if (isNetworkEnabled)
                    {
                        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                        if (locationManager != null)
                        {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null)
                            {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                    if (isGPSEnabled)
                    {
                        if (location == null)
                        {
                            // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                            if (locationManager != null)
                            {
                                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                if (location != null)
                                {
                                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return location;


    }

  //Getting user’s current location (Latitude and Longitude)
    //Get the Longitude

    public double gettheLongitude()
    { 
        if (location != null)
        {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        return longitude;
    }

    // Get the Latitude
    public double gettheLatitude()
    {
        if(location != null)
        {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        return latitude;
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation()
    {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }
    // method to get date time
    public String currentDate()
    {
        datetext = (String)DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", (new Date()).getTime());
        return datetext;
    }

  // method to get the IMEI Number by using the Context that you passed to your class
    public String getIMEINumber(){
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        // get IMEI
        String imei = tm.getDeviceId();
        return imei;
    }
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "OnCreated");
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.d(TAG, "OnStarted");
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: what is the problem what does **when i go with service i couldn't.** means

Comment: hi vaihai, put your sample code here. it would help to analyse the problem in your code.

Comment: just try to use seperate thread for GPS Listening..

Comment: Hi NetStarter,Earlier i had the problem to find as running service. But now i can view it under running services. Now I need support to send this values to Server via socket. How can I implement without service gets killed.

Comment: Here is my Receiver Class.

public class GPSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        
if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {
          
 Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,GPSTracker.class);
  
            intent1.setFlags(0x10000000);
            context.startService(intent1);
        }
 }
 }

Comment: Hi harikrishnan I put the code. I never used thread.This is my first application.Can you please give me clue..